# Better way to serialize with a timeout in c#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, timeout

My use case:
In a single threaded application,  I need to serialize arbitrary classes for logging purposes.

The arbitrary classes are predominantly translated in an automated way from a massive VB6 application into .NET.

If serialized without a timeout, the serialization method will loop until it runs out of memory.

This is what I have currently:

```cs
internal class Serializer
{
    private readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public volatile string result = null;
    public volatile Func<string> toExecute = null;
    public Thread thread;
    public ManualResetEventSlim messageToSender = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    public ManualResetEventSlim messageToReceiver = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);


    public Serializer()
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(run));
        thread.Start();
    }
    ~Serializer()
    {
        try
        {
            if (messageToSender != null) messageToSender.Dispose();
        }
        catch { };
        try
        {
            if (messageToReceiver != null) messageToReceiver.Dispose();
        }
        catch { };
    }

    public volatile bool ending = false;
    public void run()
    {
        while (!ending)
        {
            try
            {
                if (toExecute != null)
                {
                    result = toExecute();
                }
                messageToReceiver.Reset();
                messageToSender.Set();
                messageToReceiver.Wait();
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
            {
                log.Warn("Serialization interrupted");
                break;
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Thread.ResetAbort();
                result = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Error in Serialization", ex);
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class LocalStructuredLogging
{
    private static volatile Serializer _serializer;
    private static Serializer serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_serializer == null)
            {
                _serializer = new Serializer();
            }
            return _serializer;
        }
    }

    public void LogStucturedEnd()
    {
        try
        {
            if (serializer != null)
            {
                serializer.ending = true;
                serializer.thread.Interrupt();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    internal ConcurrentDictionary<long, bool> disallowedToSerialize = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, bool>();
    public string TrySerialize<T>(T payload, [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0)
    {
        long hashEl = typeof(T).Name.GetHashCode() * line;

        bool dummy;
        unchecked
        {
            if (disallowedToSerialize.TryGetValue(hashEl, out dummy))
            {
                return "°,°";
            }
        }

        serializer.toExecute = () =>
        {
            try
            {
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                disallowedToSerialize.TryAdd(hashEl, false);
                return "°°°";
            }
        };

        try
        {
            serializer.messageToSender.Reset();
            serializer.messageToReceiver.Set();

            if (serializer.messageToSender.Wait(6000))
            {
                return Interlocked.Exchange(ref serializer.result, null);
            }

            serializer.toExecute = null;
            serializer.thread.Abort();
            serializer.messageToSender.Wait(2000);

            disallowedToSerialize.TryAdd(hashEl, false);
            return "°§°";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            disallowedToSerialize.TryAdd(hashEl, false);
            return "°-°";
        }
    }
}
```

The code is called as in the following (test is an arbitrary class instance):

```
var logger = new LocalStructuredLogging();
var rr5 = logger.TrySerialize(test);
```

Although it seems to do the job, there are some issues with it:

1. it has a dependency on Thread.Abort
2. it is time dependent, so it will thus produce varied results on a loaded system
3. every class instance is treated like every other class instance - no tweaking
4. ...

So, are there any better solutions available ?

Comment: Is it an option for you to use `Task` instead of  `Thread`?

Comment: This needs a full rewrite. Current issues: this should really be run using `Task`. Use `CancellationToken` instead of throwing `ThreadAbort`. Need to implement `IDisposable` on `Serializer`. `volatile` probable doesn't do what you think it does, use `Interlocked` instead. `hashEl` is at risk of hash collisions. `Serializer` property should use `Lazy<Serializer>` But I would first think about exactly what you need to synchronize and why. Does `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` really need locking? You may be able to use `ConcurrentDictionary` and other thread-safe objects.

Comment: You could subclass `JsonTextWriter`, pass in some incoming `CancellationToken` and call `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` periodically.  See [json.net limit maxdepth when serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684280/3744182) for something similar.

Comment: Or if you simply want to limit your JSON to some maximum length, you could write to a `JsonTextWriter` constructed using a `StringWriter` constructed using a `StringBuilder` with a [`StringBuilder.MaxCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.maxcapacity?view=net-5.0) that you define.

Comment: Either way that `ConcurrentDictionary<long, bool>` looks really sketchy.  Why not simply key on a `ValueTuple<Type, int>`, e.g. `ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, int), bool>`

Comment: Task can only be the answer if Serialization does not loop forever (hence the Thread.Abort in the 1st solution)

Answer (score 1):

Based upon dbc's excellent answer, I managed to create a better timed serializer.
It resolves all 3 issues mentioned above:

```
public class TimedJsonTextWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public int? MaxDepth { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? MaxTimeUsed { get; set; }
    public int MaxObservedDepth { get; private set; }

    private DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

    public TimedJsonTextWriter(TextWriter writer, JsonSerializerSettings settings, TimeSpan? maxTimeUsed)
        : base(writer)
    {
        this.MaxDepth = (settings == null ? null : settings.MaxDepth);
        this.MaxObservedDepth = 0;
        this.MaxTimeUsed = maxTimeUsed;
    }

    public TimedJsonTextWriter(TextWriter writer, TimeSpan? maxTimeUsed, int? maxDepth = null)
        : base(writer)
    {
        this.MaxDepth = maxDepth;
        this.MaxTimeUsed = maxTimeUsed;
    }

    public override void WriteStartArray()
    {
        base.WriteStartArray();
        CheckDepth();
    }

    public override void WriteStartConstructor(string name)
    {
        base.WriteStartConstructor(name);
        CheckDepth();
    }

    public override void WriteStartObject()
    {
        base.WriteStartObject();
        CheckDepth();
    }

    uint checkDepthCounter = 0;
    private void CheckDepth()
    {
        MaxObservedDepth = Math.Max(MaxObservedDepth, Top);
        if (Top > MaxDepth)
            throw new JsonSerializationException($"Depth {Top} Exceeds MaxDepth {MaxDepth} at path \"{Path}\"");
        unchecked
        {
            if ((++checkDepthCounter & 0x3ff) == 0 && DateTime.Now - start > MaxTimeUsed)
                throw new JsonSerializationException($"Time Usage Exceeded at path \"{Path}\"");
        }
    }
}


public class LocalStructuredLogging
{
    public void LogStucturedEnd()
    {
    }

    internal HashSet<long> disallowedToSerialize = new HashSet<long>();
    public string TrySerialize<T>(T payload, int maxDepth = 100, int secondsToTimeout = 2, [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0)
    {
        long hashEl = typeof(T).Name.GetHashCode() * line;

        if (disallowedToSerialize.Contains(hashEl))
        {
            return "°,°";
        }

        try
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { MaxDepth = maxDepth, ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var jsonWriter = new TimedJsonTextWriter(writer, settings, new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondsToTimeout)))
                {
                    JsonSerializer.Create(settings).Serialize(jsonWriter, payload);
                    // Log the MaxObservedDepth here, if you want to.
                }
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            disallowedToSerialize.Add(hashEl);
            return "°-°";
        }
    }
}
```

The only issue remaining are the Hash collisions, which are easy to solve (e.g. by using the source file name as well or use another type of Collection).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to run an action timed would be to do something like the following. I would recommend taking a second look at how serialization should work as well :).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Run an action timed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">Action to execute timed.</param>
    /// <param name="secondsTimout">Seconds before Task should cancel.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task RunTimeout(Action action, int secondsTimout) {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsTimout));
        await Task.Run(action, tokenSource.Token);
    }
```

You may also want to return a variable upon the completion of your timed task. That can be done like so...

```
    public static async Task<T> RunTimeout<T>(Func<T> action, int secondsTimout) {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsTimout));
        var result = await Task.Run(action, tokenSource.Token);
        return result;
    }
```